# Connect to postgresql docker container configured with docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a postgresql server configured with docker-compose :

```yaml
version: "3"
services:

  heritagebuxfr-postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=heritagebuxfr
      - POSTGRES_USER=heritagebuxfr
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /data/heritagebuxfr-posgtres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      heritagebuxfr:
        ipv4_address: 10.8.0.5

networks:
  heritagebuxfr:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.8.0.0/16
```

When I try to connect it, it fail. Example :

```
docker run -it --rm --network root_heritagebuxfr postgres psql -h heritagebuxfr-postgres -U heritagebuxfr

psql: error: connection to server at "heritagebuxfr-postgres" (10.8.0.5), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

**How to configure my postgresql container or other container to be able to acceded ?**

Below, some additional information :

```
docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                             NAMES
5543d6f43a00   algoo/tracim:4.4.2          "/bin/bash /tracim/t…"   12 hours ago    Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:10088->80/tcp, :::10088->80/tcp                                                                                           root_heritagebuxfr_1
28739c1d135a   postgres:12                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 hours ago    Up 12 hours         5432/tcp                                                                                                                          root_heritagebuxfr-postgres_1
[...]
```

```
docker network ls

root@s2:~# docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                 DRIVER    SCOPE
924e62e9349c   bridge               bridge    local
d82517c5bf4a   host                 host      local
0a94208c6a9c   none                 null      local
794be35c7046   prestashop-net       bridge    local
3c718488b040   root_default         bridge    local
f3dafc20a876   root_dentiste74fr    bridge    local
3be74184dda3   root_heritagebuxfr   bridge    local
41db94bb460a   root_muzich          bridge    local
4c1fc0c30383   root_rocketchatmah   bridge    local
0537f6c1667f   root_tracimbuxfr     bridge    local
```

```
iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (8 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:9980
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.5.0.6             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.7.0.4             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.7.0.4             tcp dpt:3030
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:3000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.6.0.6             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.4           tcp dpt:http-alt
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:8082
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.8.0.4             tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (8 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

```
docker network inspect root_heritagebuxfr
[
    {
        "Name": "root_heritagebuxfr",
        "Id": "3b9d353561a02dd9bea8bbc66258aa120fbd464cf8fb519c4b47ed9f82110d8e",
        "Created": "2022-11-15T10:27:39.751614908Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.8.0.0/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "673decc2a8a4493fbdb01000684ed0e8f42905bea200e6efc412bd55f27fcca1": {
                "Name": "root-heritagebuxfr-postgres-1",
                "EndpointID": "35d0cd973c79758c242b9510e475e827b5c7aa6633aedb3daa655147ae89668f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:08:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "10.8.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "heritagebuxfr",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "root",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.12.2"
        }
    }
]
```

```
root@s2:~# docker --version
Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f
root@s2:~# docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471
```

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Note: I read all stack overflow answer about with subject but no one works for this configuration.

Comment: from where do you want to connect to it?

Comment: @zsolt I want to connect it from another container

Comment: show us the "docker ps" and "docker network ls" command outputs and share any other info you have

Comment: @zsolt additional information added ("docker ps" and "docker network ls" and "iptables -L")

Comment: that helped to identify your problem, see my edited answer below

Answer (score 1):

Working fine for me with Compose V2 that is the `docker compose` subcommand. Your problem is that you are still using the old docker-compose cli. Try `docker compose up` without a dash between docker and compose.

If you don't have Compose V2 yet, upgrade to it, this site walks you through it: https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-upgrade-to-docker-compose-v2/

or you can check the docker docs:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS      NAMES
f86a00472ece   postgres:12   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   5432/tcp   test-heritagebuxfr-postgres-1

$ docker network ls

NETWORK ID     NAME                                                        DRIVER    SCOPE
4f6e933d9297   test_heritagebuxfr                                          bridge    local

$ docker run -it --rm --network test_heritagebuxfr postgres psql -h heritagebuxfr-postgres -U heritagebuxfr

Password for user heritagebuxfr:
psql (15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1), server 12.13 (Debian 12.13-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

heritagebuxfr=# \l
                                                          List of databases
     Name      |     Owner     | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    | ICU Locale | Locale Provider |        Access privileges
---------------+---------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------+---------------------------------
 heritagebuxfr | heritagebuxfr | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            |
 postgres      | heritagebuxfr | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            |
 template0     | heritagebuxfr | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | =c/heritagebuxfr               +
               |               |          |            |            |            |                 | heritagebuxfr=CTc/heritagebuxfr
 template1     | heritagebuxfr | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |            | libc            | =c/heritagebuxfr               +
               |               |          |            |            |            |                 | heritagebuxfr=CTc/heritagebuxfr
(4 rows)
```

Comment: I updated to Compose V2, delete containers, delete network, recreate them with docker compose command but still don't work :(. Note I had to switch to iptable-legacy (https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/927#issuecomment-751752610) and this, before switch to compose V2.

Comment: So you are on a Debian 10 based distro (ubuntu)? what is the output of `cat /etc/os-release`?

Comment: It's a Debian 10 (migrated from debian 9). I add the command result to my question.

Comment: I added docker network detail too

Comment: I would upgrade to bullseye (11) from buster (10) because it seems that this bug appears on buster (10). I am on ubuntu 20.04 that is using bullseye.

Comment: Ouch. Do you have some source url about this bug ?

Comment: (After reading your comment again, I guess it is a guess)

Comment: Yes it is a guess based on the github issue you mentioned and the one it is also referring to: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/927#issuecomment-751752610 All the commenters on these threads have Debian 10 but maybe because Deb 11 was not yet released when the issue arised for them. If I were you I would test this theory by setting up a vm for both versions and try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time. I have to migrate to Debian 11 in next weeks. I will go back here after :)

Comment: Sure no problem! Come back here and edit your question with info if Deb 11 upgrade really solved this issue.